# How to make a JavaScript function that will return data from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

I have tried debugging in Google Chrome's Developer Console but in any way I cant get the result I want. I want to create a javascript function that will return a value from an external file through AJAX. I have tried this script:

```
var site = {
    token: function(){
        $.get('auth.php',function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
};
```

...when I call the `site.token()` function it should return the fetched contents from **auth.php**. But it just doesn't. It is always `undefined`. I also tried this:

```
var site = {
    token: function(){
        var token = null;
        $.get('auth.php',function(data){
            token = data;
        });
        return token;
    }
};
```

But its still the same. I also find a work around by doing this:

```
var token = $.get('auth.php',function(data){
    return data;
});
token.responseText;
```

With that codes, I can now get my expected result. But when I put it already in a function:

```
var site = {
    token: function(){
        var token = $.get('auth.php',function(data){
            return data;
        });
        return token.responseText;
    }
};
```

...it fails again.

> *P.S.: I don't know maybe I'm just really stressed in programming and why I can't do it right. -_-"

Comment: Ajax is still **asynchronous**

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Musa. I now understand my problem after reading the answer on the link.

Answer (score 2):

`$.post()` is short-hand for `$.ajax()`, and both are asynchronous (unless you do very bad things).  You don't want to freeze the browser's GUI thread for the duration of the request to the php page.  Thus `site.token()` can not reply with the data.

However, `$.ajax()` does return a promise (see http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/ and [how does jquery's promise method really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080050/how-does-jquerys-promise-method-really-work)).  In essence, it says "I promise I'll call you back when I'm done."  So, you can construct the class like this:

```
var site = {
    token: function(){
        var promise = $.get('auth.php',function(data){
            return data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
};
```

and call it like this:

```
var promise = site.token();
promise.done(function (data) {
    alert('got the data');
    console.dir(data);
});
```

Comment: Note that `promise.success` is deprecated.

Comment: You are correct, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is the reference.  I've updated the example to use `prompse.done()`

Comment: Thanks for answering Sir @robrich. I have taken ideas from your example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If this were possible, then the function idea could be discarded, and the syntax could just be:

```
var data = $.post("url");
```

It isn't possible however, because AJAX is asynchronous. It takes a while before the response is received. When this is the case, your function is called. That's the idea of passing a function.

There is no way to make this synchronous so as to use `return`. You can use `$.ajax` with `async: false` but it's going to be deprecated. The best you can do is `return $.post(...)` and then use `.done(...)` on the result to use the response.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, thus you use your data before it is fetched. Consider using deffered object.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/